# Spark Cassandra Connector - Input Fetch Size

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using Cassandra 3.11.4 and Spark 2.3.3. When I query lots of partition keys(for 3 months where minute is partition key = 3 * 30 * 24 * 60 partition keys) with *joinWithCassandraTable*, I'm seeing lots of slow timeout logs under cassandra **debug.log** like:

```
<SELECT * FROM event_keyspace.event_table WHERE partitionkey1, partitionkey2 = value1, value2 AND column_key = column_value1 LIMIT 5000>, time 599 msec - slow timeout 500 msec 

<SELECT * FROM event_keyspace.event_table WHERE partitionkey1, partitionkey2 = value5, value6 AND column_key = column_value5 LIMIT 5000>, time 591 msec - slow timeout 500 msec/cross-node
```

I'm using *repartitionByCassandraReplica* before *joinWithCassandraTable*.

I see that disk IO goes to 100%. If I change data model where hour goes as partition key instead of minute, large partitions will be created which is not applicable.

I suspect that this limit 5000 may cause that but even I set **input.fetch.size_in_rows** this log did not change.

```
sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.input.fetch.size_in_rows", "20000");
```

How can i set this **LIMIT 5000** clause ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reducing the spark.cassandra.input.split.size? Because all the data is falling under the same Partition.

Comment: this config changes the number of spark tasks created. my problem is fetching from cassandra.